SES drops connection (to me) at EHLO
Hi all – I’m reaching out to SF with my first question. I’m stumped on an email problem.
I have a contact form hosted at carrd.co, who uses SES to send email. I’m using this to send to a self-hosted Discourse forum under my control, using its standard internal email receiver.
Everything works in other combinations -- but SES email doesn't make it to Discourse.

the carrd.co contact form successfully sends to personal email addresses

the Discourse forum successfully receives email from personal email addresses

when sending from the carrd.co contact form to Discourse, SES drops the connection at EHLO


This is what we see in Wireshark:
12246   86.228748   54.240.69.230   64.176.213.39   SMTP    103 C: EHLO a69-230.smtp-out.amazonses.com
12247   86.228791   64.176.213.39   54.240.69.230   TCP 66  25 → 50903 [ACK] Seq=19 Ack=38 Win=44032 Len=0 TSval=958362939 TSecr=1554444418
12248   86.228963   64.176.213.39   54.240.69.230   SMTP    220 S: 250-forum-mail-receiver.localdomain | PIPELINING | SIZE 10240000 | VRFY | ETRN | ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES | 8BITMIME | DSN | CHUNKING
12253   86.236796   54.240.69.230   64.176.213.39   TCP 66  50903 → 25 [FIN, ACK] Seq=38 Ack=173 Win=28032 Len=0 TSval=1554444426 TSecr=958362939

I’ve been advised that only SES can explain why they’re dropping the connection – but Carrd.co seems unable to access logs or provide more information.
This is the first problem I’ve had with Discourse receiving email. As near as can tell through testing at MXtoolbox, everything in DNS including DKIM is correctly set up.
Is there something to look for on my end that might typically cause SES in particular to drop the connection at EHLO when other services work fine?
Thanks for any suggestions!
Update 2024-11-07:
The one mail server health test that I wasn’t passing was the SMTP banner didn’t match the domain provided by the reverse DNS PTR record.
I added a line to the Postfix config specifying
smtpd_banner: forum.[example].org ESMTP $mail_name
This resolved the flag re. SMTP banner mismatch, and the incoming mail failures changed from disconnecting at HELO to disconnecting at STARTTLS.
I'd been told that carrd.co uses “opportunitistic TLS” that should fall back to an unencrypted connection. But I finally enabled TLS, and now email from the contact form comes through.


250-forum-mail-receiver.localdomain

That MTA greets with a domain that is neither reserved nor assigned. That makes it look like it is blissfully unaware that it is accepting SMTP connections from the internet, where local nicknames or unqualified names MUST NOT be used. (You should fix that regardless of what the 220 greeting said, as information received before TLS was established is discarded.)

Thank you, anx! As I've updated above, I've gotten things working (whether they should be or not.) But I did wonder about that 250 greeting... I will look into how to change that.
